# Telegram bot to show URL iso Button

Tags: python, bots, telegram

Im using bot for auto post on my Telegram channel. Bot is posting picture, caption and three links that are showed as buttons. This all looks nice but i have difficulties when I want to share post to other platforms (twitter, reddit, wordpress...) because buttons are not recognized as links.

Here is the line of code that does that:

```
for channel in CHANNELS:
            await client.send_message(channel, CAPTION_FREE, file=f"{media}", parse_mode="HTML", buttons=[[Button.url('LINK', f'{lv_final}')],[Button.url('TUTORIAL', 'https://t.me/tutorial')],[Button.url('BACKUP CHANNELS', 'https://t.me/channel')]])
            print(Fore.GREEN + f"[{channel}] Posted {model}")
```

What and how should I change to bot post Hyperlinked text instead of buttons?